# Invalid UTF-8 Ruby strings

Tags: ruby

I'm running into some strange behaviour and inconsistency in the way that Ruby (v2.5.3) deals with encoded strings versus the YAML parser. Here's an example:

```
"\x80"          # Returns "\x80"
"\x80".bytesize # Returns 1
"\x80".bytes    # Returns [128]
"\x80".encoding # Returns UTF-8

YAML.load('{value: "\x80"}')["value"]          # Returns "\u0080"
YAML.load('{value: "\x80"}')["value"].bytesize # Returns 2
YAML.load('{value: "\x80"}')["value"].bytes    # Returns [194, 128]
YAML.load('{value: "\x80"}')["value"].encoding # Returns UTF-8
```

My understanding of UTF-8 is that any single-byte value above `0x7F` should be encoded into two bytes. So my questions are the following:

1. Is the one byte string `"\x80"` valid UTF-8?
2. If so, why does YAML convert into a two-byte pattern?
3. If not, why is Ruby claiming the encoding is UTF-8 but containing an invalid byte sequence?
4. Is there a way to make the YAML parser and the Ruby string behave in the same way as each other?

Comment: `"\x80".valid_encoding?` definitely invalid. Not sure what YAML is doing though

Comment: Excellent point -- I assumed it would throw an error or something when you tried to set it, but I guess it just allows the string and says it's invalid if you bother to check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not valid UTF-8

```
"\x80".valid_encoding?
# false
```

Ruby is claiming it is UTF-8 because all String literals are UTF-8 by default, even if that makes them invalid.

I don't think you can force the YAML parser to return invalid UTF-8. But to get Ruby to convert that character you can do this

```
"\x80".b.ord.chr('utf-8')
# "\u0080"
```

`.b` is only available in Ruby 2+. You need to use `force_encoding` otherwise.